# Having Trouble with Inner Classes

Tags: python, class

I am having trouble getting my small program to work while using an inner class.
When, I set a inside class member variable from the outside class, the value does not stick. Thanks.

Here is my source code:

```
class Erik:

    def __init__(self):

        self.__myData = self.Data()


    class Data:
        def __init__(self):

            self.__privateNumber = 0

        def getNumber(self):
            return self.__privateNumber

    def getData(self):
        return self.__myData


    def fun(self):

        self.__myData.__privateNumber = 64

        print 'Private Number Inside:', self.__myData.__privateNumber


myErik = Erik()

print 'Having fun...'
myErik.fun()

# This print statement should output '64'
print 'Private Number Outside:', myErik.getData().getNumber()
```

This is the output of my script:

```
C:\Users\Erik\Desktop\PYTHON_TINKER_DEALS>python erik.py
Having fun...
Private Number Inside: 64
Private Number Outside: 0
```

As you see, when I set the private number to 64, it does not reflect that when you get the data from the outer class.
Thanks.

Comment: what problem do you think inner classes solve?

Answer (score 0):

The variable name is prefixed with a double underscore so the name is mangled (see [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables)), so you are referencing a different variable from inside and outside the class.

One way to make it work would be to remove the double underscore. Make the variable name

```
privateNumber
```

Even a single underscore does not seem appropriate here as you intend to reference the variable from outside the sub class.

If you wanted to keep the `__` you would just create a setter function for the value and set it through that and read it through the getter.

i.e.

```
class Data:
    # ....
    def setNumber(self, num):
        self.__privateNumber = num
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of the [`__`-induced name mangling](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references), `self.__myData.__privateNumber` that you set in `Erik.fun` is not the same variable that is initialized in `Data.__init__`. You can see this by changing the two references in `Erik.fun` to their mangled form:

```
def fun(self):
    self.__myData._Data.__privateNumber = 64
    print 'Private Number Inside:', self.__myData._Data__privateNumber
```

In general, though, you only need to use `__`-prefixed names if you are concerned about a subclass overriding a private variable. Also, nested classes are rarely used in Python; `Data` can be declared outside `Erik` unless you have a really good reason for including it inside `Erik`. Finally, you should *always* explicitly inherit from `object` to avoid creating an old-style class.

```
class Erik(object):
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are making all your variables private?
Python's attitude to private variables is that "we're all adults here", so nothing is really private. What is does do is [mangle](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references) the names of "private" variables. If you want to access `self.__myData.__privateNumber` inside `fun()` you need to use the mangled name. I.e. `self._Erik__myData._Data__privateNumber`. Where you think that you're reassigning the value, what you're really doing is creating a new property.